# How to access infromation from parent model Django HTML Tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a two formsets rendered in a view called ContactIndex, the parent model for this view is the CustomUser model. I want to present the first_name of the user object in my html template. I've tried these tags without success any advise?

This is the tags in my HTML template:

`{{ customuser.first_name }}` - does not work

`{{ object.first_name }}` - does not work

**This is my view:**

```
def ContactIndex(request, CustomUser_id):
        customuser = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=CustomUser_id)
        if request.method == "POST":
            ContactFormset = ContactInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=customuser)
            AddressFormset = AddressInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=customuser)
            if ContactFormset.is_valid() or AddressFormset.is_valid():
                AddressFormset.save()
                ContactFormset.save()
                # Do something. Should generally end with a redirect. For example:
                return redirect ('ContactIndex', CustomUser_id=customuser.id)
        else:
            ContactFormset = ContactInlineFormSet(instance=customuser)
            AddressFormset = AddressInlineFormSet(instance=customuser)
        return render(request, 'members/member_contact_form.html', {'ContactFormset':ContactFormset, 'Address

Formset':AddressFormset })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get access to it by

```
{% for form in ContactFormset %}
    {{ form.instance.MODEL_FIELD_NAME }}
{% endform %}
```

if you need to get instance outside the form loop, you better provide additional context

```
return render(request, 'members/member_contact_form.html', {
    'ContactFormset':ContactFormset, 
    'AddressFormset':AddressFormset,
    'customuser': customuser,
})
```